# Webpack: Create a bundle with each file in directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am trying to bundle every angular module in webpack. My target is to have one app.js that will be bundled by webpack with this configuration:

```
entry: {
        app: "./app/app.js"
},
output: {
        path: "./build/ClientBin",
        filename: "bundle.js"
},
```

I will place this bundle script in my index.html so it will entry point of my app.
Also I have many modules in `./app/components` folder. Folder structure in like:

```
app
|--components
|  |
|  |--home
|  |  |
|  |  |--home.html
|  |  |--home.js
|--app.js
|--AppController.js
```

I have required `home.html` in `home.js` so when I load `home.js` all of its needed files will load.
The problem is I have several components like `home` and I want to tell webpack to bundle each component separately and name it with its containing folder like `home`.

How can I config webpack to create these bundles and put them in `./build/components`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up defining entries programmatically. I wrote this in my webpack.config.js:

```
function getDirectories(srcpath) {
    return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
    });
}

var entry = {
    app: "./app/app.ts",
    vendor: ["angular", "oclazyload", "angular-new-router", "lodash"]
};
var components = getDirectories("./app/components");
for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    entry[components[i]] = "./app/components/" + components[i] + "/" + components[i] + ".ts";
}
```

And then used `entry` variable in config.

Answer (score 27):

A simpler way:

Use globs in your `webpack.config.js`:

Here's an example:

```
var glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
     js: glob.sync("./app/components/**/*.js"),  
  }
}
```

Comment: Although the accepted answer uses out of the box tools, this is by far the simplest, and my preferred answer.

Comment: make sure to install webpack-glob with npm first. `npm install webpack-glob --save-dev`

Comment: Can anyone show what the entire `webpack.config.js` file would look like?  For example, what should the `output` value be?

Comment: `npm install webpack-glob --save-dev` in my project produced +356 packages in node_modules and +23 vulnerabilities, 2 of which CRITICAL

Comment: Yeah DONT use webpack-glob. It is no longer maintained. You can just use `glob`

Answer (score 6):

To have each file exported individually, you can use the following code snippet to do so:

```
const glob = require('glob')
const path = require('path')

const entryFiles = glob.sync('./app/components/**/*.js').reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
  return typeof previousValue === 'string' ?
    {
      [path.basename(previousValue, path.extname(previousValue))]: previousValue,
      [path.basename(currentValue, path.extname(currentValue))]: currentValue
    }
    :
    { ...previousValue, [path.basename(currentValue, path.extname(currentValue))]: currentValue }
})

module.exports = {
  entry: entryFiles,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'ClientBin')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
entry: {
    home: './app/app.js',
    page: './page/app.js',
},
output: {
    path: './build/ClientBin',
    filename: '[name].js',
},
```

This will generate `home.js` and `page.js` at your output path. Tweak, generalize as needed. You'll probably want to extract those entry paths to a variable and so on.

Note that with a bit of tweaking you are likely able to output the bundles exactly where you want. I expect you would then use a `path` like `./app/components/[name]` or so.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many entries I will have. I have edited the question to show my workaround, but I am searching for an out of the box solution.

Comment: Your solution looks good to me. Being a configuration driven tool Webpack doesn't really care how you generate the configuration as long as it's right.

Comment: Sounds logical! So how do I have to complete this question workflow? I mean I have to put that edited part to an answer?