# How to properly have multiple react components?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So I have a web app built in php laravel, we are using it for the routing and database. Now I want to use react components on certain pages, I don't want to build the complete site in react. But I keep getting an error because webpack compiles everything into one file.

**localhost/home this works perfectly**

```
<div class="app">

</div>
```

but when I go

**localhost/about this error comes up**

final.min.js:1 Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

```
//this don't have <div class="app">
```

so how can I make the components show up on specific pages?

Comment: You can build components to separate files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818236/webpack-create-a-bundle-with-each-file-in-directory and then include on page you want

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend giving your div an id to identify it.

```
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Then check with JavaScript if this div exists on the current page. Only render your react components if this div exists.

```
var app = document.getElementById('app');
if (typeof app !== 'undefined') { // or just if (app) {
    ReactDOM.render(yourReactElement, app);
}
```

Comment: That should probably be `getElementById('app')`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having a look at the [React Habitat library](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat).

Since you don't want everything in React i think this is most suited framework to your problem. With this you can just register components and render them in the DOM where needed.

Example

Register component(s):

```
container.register('MyComponent', MyComponent);
container.register('MySecondComponent', MySecondComponent);
```

Then they are available in your DOM like this:

```
<div data-component="MyComponent"></div>

<div data-component="MySecondComponent"></div>
```

The above will be automatically replaced with your react components.

I would be wary using a Router, as your app could break if the urls are managed and changed else where (eg in your php code).

Answer (score -1):

I use https://github.com/reactjs/react-router .

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```