# Building es6 classes into separate files with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I'm, trying to set up a repository for my commonly used react components that I could then add to my projects like `component-kit` and reuse these, so something like

```
import MyComponent from 'component-kit/MyComponent';
```

At the moment I have following project structure:

```
component-kit/
   src/
     MyComponent/
       index.js
     index.js
   package.json
   webpack.config.js
```

`index.js` file imports all components in the following way:

```
import('./MyComponent');
```

And I then use webpack to build each of these imports into separate files, here is my config as per code splitting docs available [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/#usage-with-babel)

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'dist.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
            plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

At the moment this outputs 2 files `dist.js` and `0.dist.js` and I can't figure out how to set this up in a way where files outputet have component names i.e. `MyComponent.js` so I can than include it like mentioned above.
ideally these would not include react into their build as it will always be present in parent components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use babel for this purpose if you use a babel based language like JSX.
Take a look at [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/package.json#L29) material-ui npm script.
Webpack is generally good for bundling production applications I think.
You can get file names using node `fs` and dynamically generate entries like [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30860951/2245902) if you insist on using webpack.